# Do we *really* want this new "add a comment" link?

Tags: discussion, comments, design

[image: New comment whatsit]

So, we've had discussions about the comment unfolding before, but I can't find any post that explicitly mentions the fact that a change was rolled out today. The change is to add "add a comment | " before the unfolding link; previously, it showed up only when no unfolding was needed or after performing unfolding.

We'll gloss over for a moment the fact that this seems fairly arbitrary and ruins my well-honed workflow (I keep clicking on the wrong bl00dy link, now!).

**Who adds a comment before reading the whole comment thread?** Why are we encouraging such nonsense behaviour?!

Comment: **Disclaimer:** At least, I _think_ it was rolled out today. And I _think_ that's how it worked before...

Comment: I didn't liked the new one

Comment: Related: [Proposed tweak to comment UI for long threads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235255)

Comment: This: http://xkcd.com/1172/.

Comment: @dav_i: In anticipation of the inevitable anti-anti-change comments, I provided a genuine practical issue in the final paragraph!

Comment: I also wonder if there aren't far more important issues on the backlog that devs could be looking at...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I actually agree with you! Just always relish the opportunity to link to an XKCD comic!

Comment: I don't think it's really a problem clicking on the wrong thing. *If you click "add a comment" in the new version, it will still expand any hidden comments*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does expand the comments though when you click on *Add a comment*

Comment: I like that the functionality *exists* now - that damn text entry field gets in my way all the time when I just want to read comments. Not wild about the positioning, but haven't used it enough yet to have strong feelings.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Orly. So what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Really, your muscle memory is enough to condemn any change? Why not wait a little and see how it pans out before you pan a feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, The "show X more comments" one doesn't put the box to add a comment in your way. I've never really seen that as a problem, but it would seem some do (hint: go three comments up).

Comment: FWIW, *I* kept clicking the wrong link before when the "Add comment" link suddenly kept changing to "2 more comments" the exact second I tried to click it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit One difference, if you click on show more **comment**, it won't open comment box for you

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I still instinctively reach for the little latch next to the drive bay when trying to insert a USB stick; just one of those holdovers from the 5¼" floppy days. Can't help it mate...

Comment: I like the new functionality since I am reading a lot on my Ipad. The keyboard is not jump in when I want to read more comment.

Comment: What do you do most? Read more comments or add a new comment?

Comment: Still, maybe the "add a new comment" and "show more comments" should be swapped, as I tend to read new comments more.

Comment: @milleniumbug We're definitely open to that idea. I'm going to let this current change breathe for a little while, but I am making note of suggestions people report on metas.

Comment: That would work for me.

Comment: Oohhhhh, shiny!

Comment: No matter how much the community doesn’t want it, they won’t change it back anyway.

Comment: I didn't read the above comments, but yeah, LRiO's point makes sense to me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The "add comment" and "show x more comments" buttons were separated today; you're correct about that. The previous version had an "add / show x more comments" all as a single UI element.

You can read the [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads) for all the details, but splitting these into two actions was deliberate. I feel like your concerns are a bit premature at the moment; the "add comment" button, when clicked, expands all hidden comments and exposes a text field to add your own – **which is *exactly* what the old button did**.

- The "add comment" button expands all hidden comments and exposes the comment input field.
- The "show x more comments" button expands all hidden comments *without* displaying a giant text box for adding a new comment.

We don't want people to add comments without reading existing ones. That's why hidden comments expand regardless of which button you choose. Many people look for an "add comment" button, and *some* of those people might not realize that they aren't seeing everything that's already been posted.

We're keeping an eye on the effects of this change. If it winds up that we see substantially more comments submitted, or substantial confusion, we'll consider additional changes. This isn't meant to be a "change it, then leave it forever" type of change, but we previously weren't really tracking comment behavior very well. Splitting these two buttons allows us to get a baseline of user intentions, and we can make additional changes as necessary – including, but not limiting to, rearranging the order of those buttons, moving their placement on the page entirely, or some other option we haven't explored yet.

Let's see it in action for a while before making judgements about it.

Comment: A giant text box, **plus** the on-screen keyboard on my iPad, which I then have to close because in practice it came down to "Show *last* comment only".

Comment: Thanks for the change. Could you mark https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117351/add-show-comments-focuses-text-box-by-default as status-completed?

Comment: Now that they're broken out, why not move the "show all comments" link to the top? That way I know before I start reading that it's an abridged conversation?

Comment: Can you flip them? I don't know about everyone else but I read left to right - if pushing users to look at previous (hidden) comments is preferred, I would've thought putting that link on the left (where their eyes will go first) makes more sense.

Comment: I think the text should be inverted, but I don't really have a good reason why.

Comment: +1 for @Gabe. If I'm reading comments and there are some hidden, I will always expand them and then I have to read the comments again. If it's at the top, I can expand from the start and read just once.

Comment: Personally, I hate this change. I have to spend a little extra effort now to figure out which link to click (to make sure I don't click the wrong one), while before there was only one link to click, so that wasn't a problem.

Comment: I like this because I use the up-down keys on the keyboard most of the time. I use a trackball and it's easier to scroll with the keys. So clicking the original link put the cursor into the textbox, which meant additional clicks (after moving away from the mouse) to use the up-down keys. And I'm only editing because "enter" saved my edits, is that by design, too?

I agree with others that the expand comments link would be nice at the top of the comments, so I don't have to re-read everything to catch what I missed.