# Unfriendly ux when trying to "add a comment"

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've noticed this but haven't mentioned it but I'm annoyed by it.  Let's say you go to a question that has a lot of comments, take this post: [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)

If I click the **add a comment** hyperlink it suddenly opens the textbox but opens up ALL the comments associated with the thread and pushes the text box down, here's a screen cast video showing the issue: http://screencast.com/t/PSQ15LMvI5

Notice after I click add a comment I have to scroll and scroll and scroll until I've finally found the comment textbox.  Why can't we anchor down or scroll down directly to the comment box auto-magically?

Comment: I remember that it was decided to keep it like that because consistency with [something or something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235255/213575). Can't find it in the comments of the post that announced the changes.

Comment: Oh, found it, it wasn't on comments: "If you click "add a comment" in the new version, it will still expand any hidden comments; **we still want you to read what's there before posting your own thoughts**"

Comment: @Braiam - There is so much content there but if someone decided that keeping it that way was a good idea then I will continue banging my head on the wall.  What in the hell do people think this is!

Comment: Braiam - That is utter nonsense...okay open the comments but bring me the comment box back.  I'm not going to go through a plethora of comments (in my example almost hundreds) just to get to a textbox.  In most cases, the rest of the comments are simply noise to me.  My comment may have nothing to do with what is being talked about.  It's a personal question / comment I want to make.  Some of the UX decisions on the functionality of these sites needs to  be looked at.  This one is a prime candidate.

Comment: Yeah, not having the viewport focused on the comment box may cause some head-banging... luckily the cursor is focused on the box, so if you start typing (and don't forget what you were supposed to write) it should focus again... But reading it deeper, they were supposed to gather data about the behavior and adjust accordingly, wonder what happened with that?

Comment: `wonder what happened with that`...obviously nothing.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think it's for consistency. [Laura said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266815/176646), "We don't want people to add comments without reading existing ones. That's why hidden comments expand regardless of which button you choose. Many people look for an 'add comment' button, and some of those people might not realize that they aren't seeing everything that's already been posted."

Comment: Just... start writing? Browser should scroll down to show the `<textarea>` (at least Chrome does that).

Comment: If there are already hundreds of comments... does there really need to be another one? Nobody is going to see it anyway, since it will be buried deep within the comment collapse.

Answer (score 5):

<s>That's not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but explicitly [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as Braiam commented.</s>

You *should not* add a comment *unless* you have read *all* the comments and yours really adds something.

Now, I concede it's annoying having to scroll through all the comments I *already* read when re-visiting a post with a long comment-thread.
But how should the site know where I should resume reading anyway?

(It would be nice if the coments which were not hidden were marked some way. Most of the time, that selection is relatiely static....)

---

Now that it's retagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), *everything* I wrote still applies, and the request should simply be declined due to too much collateral damage.
At least some people might, the way things are now, deign to read the pre-existing comments, instead of being encouraged to ignore them. Reducing that percentage means more useless duplicate comments to wade through, which is inacceptable.

Comment: They should re-tag it `status-confusing`